# Unable to install Docker on Ubuntu 22.04.2

Tags: apt, software-installation, dpkg, docker

I am following the installation guide on Docker for Ubuntu: https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/

I have downloaded the Ubuntu deb file, when i run Docker Desktop, it shows the following error:
[image]

I also tried Setting up and installing Docker Engine from Docker’s apt repository.

I ran this command in the terminal

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ca-certificates curl gnupg
```

I have the following unmet dependencies.

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 docker-desktop : Depends: qemu-system-x86 (>= 5.2.0) but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: docker-ce-cli but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: pass but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: uidmap
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

How do i download Docker, either from Docker Desktop or from the apt's repository